# Custom location for menu

Tags: menus, navigation

Does anyone know why when I the code to implement the menu it displays the menu right after the body tag.

And this is where I add my code

```
<div class='nav'>
    <a href='#' class='menu_btn'>Menu</a>
    " . wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location'=>'primary')) ."
</div>
```

Comment: Are the lack of PHP tags on purpose? `<?php wp_nav_menu(...); ?>`

Comment: Yes because its inside an echo. Maybe that is causing the problem?

Comment: By default wp nav menu echos itself

Comment: Yes but I cant use php tags because I already used echo at the top

Comment: And you can't use this as it is because 2 echos don't make a right. [Look at the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [add the `echo` argument](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Parameters) so that function *returns* the menu:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location'=>'primary', 'echo' => false ) )
```